# Missing Apps in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app

I am using SharePoint Online/365.
When I attempt to add an app I only am given the option of doc library, custom list, tasks, and site mailbox.

I know that there are other apps including announcements, calendars, etc.

I have verified that my Team Collaboration Lists feature is activated under 'Manage Features'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should you try to deactivate and activate it again ? also what's the current site template that you are using ?

Comment: Try to delete browser cache, different browser or in-private browsing. It looks some scripting issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and found a less-than-ideal workaround:

1. Create a different site (I created mine as a team site).
2. On that site, go to "Add an App", the desired app should be
   available,
3. click on the app, then click "Advanced Options" which will open in a
   new tab. Now copy the part of the URL that begins with "_layouts/"
   all the way to the end,
4. then go back to the original site and paste it into the site URL
   after the site's path and hit enter. Ex:
   `https://companysite.sharepoint.com/sites/originalsite/_layouts/long-string-of-chars`

*Again, this isn't ideal, but it should work.*
 If the second site doesn't have the desired app, you may need to make sure Team Collaboration Lists is active.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer would be to provide the 'Add a (classic) app' url.

{WebURL}/_layouts/15/addanapp.aspx

If that doesn't work, look to adjust feature settings.